# Can't get data from controller as json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, model-view-controller, controller

I need to get the data from controller to the View as JSON format, but it doesn't work and i don't get it why.

My controller (i request it on the index action):

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        CompanyTicketsDb _db = new CompanyTicketsDb();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model =
                _db.Tickets
                    .Select(r => new TicketListViewModel
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Description = r.Description,
                        CompanyName = r.CompanyName,
                        Status = r.Status,
                        CompanyId = r.CompanyId,
                    });
            if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            } 

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And my view (It is a partial view) looks liek that (Test mode):

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.TicketListViewModel>

<button id="Button1">asd</button>

@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
                type: 'GET'
                url = '/';
                dataType = 'json';
                contentType = 'application/json';
                success = function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log("asd");
                };
                error = function () { alert("Error retrieving employee data!"); };

            });
        });

    </script>

}
```

The thing is that i don't get any message (nor allert or console log) to test if returned JSON is valid so after that i could use them to fill View.

Comment: It didn't solved. Got some others various problems. at the moment trying to solve it. Got syntax errors for comma and ':', so added $.ajax({ - it gives no errors, but i still don't get any result :<

Comment: Looks that i managed to fix. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your syntax is wrong. You are using '=' but you should use ':'.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.TicketListViewModel>

<button id="Button1">asd</button>

@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET'
                url : '/';
                dataType : 'json';
                contentType : 'application/json';
                success : function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log("asd");
            };
            error : function () { alert("Error retrieving employee data!"); };

        });
    });

</script>

}
```